# Firebase not updating callback when there is no internet connection

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using firebase with persistence enabled, works fine, but the problem is when there is no local data and no internet connection, firebase continues to load with its auto retries. I do not see any option to set maximum retry, so that after MAX_RETRY it would update the callback method ***onRequestFailed()*** saying *The operation could not be performed due to a network error*

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I have enabled local persistence, so that it saves all the data locally, but at very first time if there is no internet connection, it is not updating onRequestFailed() method

Comment: Why should the request fail if there is no data?

Comment: Basically Firebase checks data availability locally, if there is no data, it polls server. I expect it to check status of the internet connection, and if it is not reachable it should update the onRequestFalied() callback where DatabaseError object is passed from which we can extract the message. Pl correct me if I'm wrong!